# Laravel TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53:

Tags: php, laravel

Имеется html код

```
<form method="post" action="/addComment" class="comments-add-area-entry">
  <div class="comments-add-area-entry-top">
    <div class="input">
      <label>Введите Ваше имя</label>
      <input type="text">
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
      <label>Введите Ваш e-mail</label>
      <input type="text">
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
      <label>Введите Ваш комментарий</label>
      <textarea></textarea>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
      <button><i class="fa fa-commenting"></i>Добавить комментарий</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

И контроллер

```
public function addComment() { echo "hello world"; }
```

Дело в том, что когда прохожу по адресу, то все выдается нормально, а когда перехожу через форму выдает:

> TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53:

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно в форму вставить *CSRF токен*

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
```

а если у вас blade

```
{!! csrf_field() !!}
```

Comment: Добавлю, что почитать об этом можно [здесь - Laravel5, csrf-защита](https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/routing#csrf-защита)